# Window Identity Foundation cookies work flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, single-sign-on, wif

Can anyone explain me how claim transfer flow between two application (STS & relying party) in WIF? I know claim transfer via cookie but not able to understand how cookie information transfer between two domain.

I had existing STS (WIF) implemented application and I have create new relying party (new website) and integrated with existing STS which is working expected.

I have noted below steps on browser console when I tried to open relying party application

1. https://onlineaccount.abc.com (status 302)
2. https://security.abc.com/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%.....(status 302)
3. https://security.abc.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f%3fw...(status 200)

After submit login form

4. https://security.abc.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f%3... (status 302 and created form authentication cookies)
5. https://security.abc.com/?wa=wsignin1... (status 302 and created plain cookie with relying party url)
6. https://onlineaccount.abc.com/ (status 302 and created (i) send SAML token in form data and create FedAuth cookie in response)
7. https://onlineaccount.abc.com/ (status 200)

As per above steps what I understand that FedAuth cookie set by relying party application but how relying party application receive token/claim information (SAML token information)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep looking into browser (specially IE), I got my answer, how STS application sharing data to relying party...

**Answer in simple Word** - STS application submits hidden Form to relying party application with security token.

[image]

1. http://security.STS.Web/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f%3... 

    **In this request STS server simple creates form Authentication cookie**
2. http://security.STS.Web/?wa=wsignin1... 

    **In this request 
    1. STS server simple creates simple cookie with relying party name. 
    2. STS server will submit one hidden form with token information for relying party (see below attachment)**

[image]

3. http:/// (http://localhost:52255/)
   **In this request relying party will receive token information (which is submitted by STS application) and creates FedAuth cookie and redirect to relying party default page**
4. http://localhost:52255/Default.aspx